# Сумма последних 10 строк

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT sum(`t`) as t, sum(`g`) as g FROM `trans` WHERE `done` = 'true' ORDER BY  `trans`.`id` DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

нужно что бы запрос брал последние 10 строк и считал сумму в t и g, а он считает сумму во всем столбце (
кто поправит?

Answer (score 2):

Cделайте ваш селект вложенным, например:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/489ebb/3)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE  VIEW `generator_16` AS select 0 AS `n` union all select 1 AS `1` union all select 2 AS `2` union all select 3 AS `3` union all select 4 AS `4` union all select 5 AS `5` union all select 6 AS `6` union all select 7 AS `7` union all select 8 AS `8` union all select 9 AS `9` union all select 10 AS `10` union all select 11 AS `11` union all select 12 AS `12` union all select 13 AS `13` union all select 14 AS `14` union all select 15 AS `15`;
CREATE VIEW `generator_256` AS select ((`hi`.`n` << 4) | `lo`.`n`) AS `n` from (`generator_16` `lo` join `generator_16` `hi`);
CREATE VIEW `generator_4k` AS select ((`hi`.`n` << 8) | `lo`.`n`) AS `n` from (`generator_256` `lo` join `generator_16` `hi`);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT n FROM generator_4k ORDER BY n DESC limit 10
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/489ebb/3/0)**:

```
|    N |
|------|
| 4095 |
| 4094 |
| 4093 |
| 4092 |
| 4091 |
| 4090 |
| 4089 |
| 4088 |
| 4087 |
| 4086 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT SUM(n) FROM 
    (SELECT n FROM generator_4k ORDER BY n DESC limit 10) gen4k
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/489ebb/3/1)**:

```
| SUM(N) |
|--------|
|  40905 |
```